# What could keep Clonezilla from booting on an older laptop?

Tags: boot, laptop, clonezilla

I'm trying to use Clonezilla to clone a drive on an old Toshiba Sattelite with an Intel Centrino Duo processor. It's booting off of a 256 MB USB drive. It works fine on my desktop, but on the laptop I just get a blinking cursor.

The BIOS is set to boot from the USB first, I'm not seeing any other BIOS settings that would affect it other than the legacy USB support setting.

I've seen stories of people using clonezilla on older machines. Any ideas why it won't boot on this particular machine?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the laptop was old enough it didn't support 64 bit, but burning a CD with 32 bit Clonezilla worked.